# Spring form saves two similar values for one field

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc

I have a spring form bind to object. When form submitted I get Object's name field with `additional name`. E.g. field value is "`test`". When it is saved it becomes "`test,test`". If saved again then it becomes "`test,test,test`".

I have binded form field as

```
<form:input path="groupName" id="groupName" />
```

Comment: scan the jsp to make sure two form components have not been given the same path of groupName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be sending two values for same parameter.

One will be going through for post parameter and one will be going in action URL as get parameter.